# Three JS - OrbitControls wobble when rotating

Tags: typescript, three.js

I'm using currently developing a scene with threejs, and am using the orbit controls to rotate the camera around the scene. I've noticed that every now and again, when rotating around, it sometimes starts throwing my camera all around the place, then it seems to resolve itself and rotates smoothly.

I've seen a few posts online about an orbit control wobble, but they're issue seems to mainly be when the camera is static, this happens on and off, only when rotating.

[small video of what I mean](https://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cFQX2nqmhZ)

You can see it's wobbling around, then I focus into object and back out, then it's fine.

I've seen some solutions involving near and far clipping planes, mine are currently:

`nearClippingPlane = 0.1`

`farClippingPlane = 10000`

Would you say it's something to do with that? And therefore I should explore those solutions further?

Or is it a different issue?

Thanks guys, and once again, sorry for what is probably a trivial question...

**EDIT:**

Here's the renderloop:

https://ibb.co/hLLmqU

Here's another video where I'm trying to avoid mousing over the cubes:

https://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cFQXoCqmlS

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it applies both orbitcontrols rotate and the zoom on the cubes you have done when raycast intersects them. Notice how it works fine when you grab space without the raycast hitting the cubes and when you grab cube it starts zooming and going back every frame. Try changing zoom event from mousedown to click.

Comment: Do you mean 'zoom' as in when I clicked a cube and moved into it? On mouseup it creates a bezier curve and lerps the cameras position along that, it doesn't change the camera's zoom value, it literally moves towards the cube. I've also got orbit controls zoom and pan disabled if that's actually what ya meant, just rotate is enabled. I just disabled the cubes from receiving raycasts and made sure I'm not passing the mouse over the cubes when I rotate, and it's still doing it :'-(

Comment: Edited OP, I'm currently doing a work placement at a company, so I'm following their conventions (if it looks funky)

Comment: This has ceased to occur, don't ask why, I would post solution if I knew, but thanks for response dude